# get users which are connected together

Tags: mysql

If I'm logged in as a teacher, I would like to get the `student` and the `parents`. If I'm logged in as a `parent` I would like to get the student and the `teachers`. Lastly, if I'm logged in as a student, I would like to get the `teacher` and `parents`

Here is how my table is set up

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO users (name)
VALUES ("Gregor (Student)"),
    ("Louise (Student)"),
    ("Liza (Teacher)"),
    ("Matt (Teacher)"),
    ("Bob (Parent)"),
    ("Wilma (Parent)"),
    ("Tim (Parent)");
    
CREATE TABLE school(
    student_id INT,
    teacher_id INT NULL,
    parent_id INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`, `teacher_id`, `parent_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`teacher_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO school (student_id, teacher_id, parent_id)
VALUES (1, 3, 5),
(1, 4, NULL),
(2, 3, 6),
(2, 4, 7);
```

My current query:

```
SELECT u.name AS student, t.name AS teacher, p.name AS parent FROM school s INNER JOIN users u ON (u.id = s.student_id) LEFT JOIN users t ON (t.id = s.teacher_id) LEFT JOIN users p ON (p.id = s.parent_id) WHERE (s.student_id = 1 OR s.teacher_id = 1 OR s.parent_id = 1);
```

What I get now:

```
student | teacher | parent
Gregor, |Liza, Matt|, Bob
Gregor, |Liza|, NULL
```

What I expect depend on which user is logged in.

So if I'm logged in as Bob, because Bob is only connected to one student:

```
student | teacher | parent
Gregor, |Liza, Matt|, Bob
```

if I'm logged in as Liza, because Liza is present in both students:

```
student | teacher | parent
Gregor, |Liza, Matt|, Bob
Louise, |Liza, Matt|, Wilma, Tim
```

Comment: i think your schema is wrong,  make student table, parent table and teachers table, then make relationship between them.

Comment: Seems reasonable but I think it should be possible with the current schema

Comment: the school table is so not possible neiter with mysql 5.7 nor 8.028

Comment: Any suggestions @nbk?

Comment: @LuveCode see my answer and look into the fiddle, you see that  school and its promary key has to be not NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have multiple rows per student you need a `GROUP BY` and a `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine the rows that belong together

> ```
> SELECT 
>     u.name AS student, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS teacher, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) AS parent
> FROM
>     school s
>         INNER JOIN
>     users u ON (u.id = s.student_id)
>         LEFT JOIN
>     users t ON (t.id = s.teacher_id)
>         LEFT JOIN
>     users p ON (p.id = s.parent_id)
> #WHERE
>  #  (s.student_id = 1 OR s.teacher_id = 1
>  #      OR s.parent_id = 1)
>  GROUP BY student;
> ```
>
> ```
> student          | teacher                       | parent                     
> :--------------- | :---------------------------- | :--------------------------
> Gregor (Student) | Liza (Teacher),Matt (Teacher) | Bob (Parent)               
> Louise (Student) | Liza (Teacher),Matt (Teacher) | Wilma (Parent),Tim (Parent)
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cb40068b7c87e56de4b7b71760365c23)*

## here are sample how you would find someone by name

> ```
> SELECT 
>     u.name AS student, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS teacher, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) AS parent
> FROM
>     school s
>         INNER JOIN
>     users u ON (u.id = s.student_id)
>         LEFT JOIN
>     users t ON (t.id = s.teacher_id)
>         LEFT JOIN
>     users p ON (p.id = s.parent_id)
> WHERE
>    (u.name LIKE  'Liza%' 
>    OR t.name LIKE  'Liza%'
>        OR p.name LIKE 'Liza%'
>        )
>  GROUP BY student;
> ```
>
> ```
> student          | teacher        | parent        
> :--------------- | :------------- | :-------------
> Gregor (Student) | Liza (Teacher) | Bob (Parent)  
> Louise (Student) | Liza (Teacher) | Wilma (Parent)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     u.name AS student, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS teacher, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) AS parent
> FROM
>     school s
>         INNER JOIN
>     users u ON (u.id = s.student_id)
>         LEFT JOIN
>     users t ON (t.id = s.teacher_id)
>         LEFT JOIN
>     users p ON (p.id = s.parent_id)
> WHERE
>    (u.name LIKE  'Bob%' 
>    OR t.name LIKE  'Bob%'
>        OR p.name LIKE 'Bob%'
>        )
>  GROUP BY student;
> ```
>
> ```
> student          | teacher        | parent      
> :--------------- | :------------- | :-----------
> Gregor (Student) | Liza (Teacher) | Bob (Parent)
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6232aa79867bb0e8a633c2a8348c0acc)*

Comment: This is just awesome, i see what you mean. But question, i get now both rows and it's not depended on my WHERE condition. My aim was to, if i was logged in e.g as Bob i should get the first row. But if i was logged in as Matt (Teacher) i should get both row. Now it does not check who is logged in without the WHERE condition.

Is it uncomment for testing purposes? Is the WHERE condition the right way to do it?

Comment: i removed the where condition as your wanted result is exactly as i wroet in my answer with both student, remove the `#` and you will receive only the first row, what defeats the purpose to showing you what is the solution

Comment: Sorry, i may confused the result i want. So i rewrote the result in my post. Hopefully i made it more clear. Is it possible to just include the WHERE condition to get the result i want?

Comment: That is simple basic sql to consruct a Where clause, but i added the samples for Liza and bob

Comment: Awesome mate, i learned so much. Thank you!